# Probability integral transforms of risk-neutral densities

Tags: programming, implied-volatility, risk-neutral-measure

I've backed out a time series of risk-neutral densities of GBP/USD options using a non-parametric approach in Matlab and would like to assess their forecast ability by applying the unconditional test in section 2.3 (page 11) of Christoffersen and Mazzotta "[The Accuracy of Density Forecasts from Foreign Exchange Options](https://www.mcgill.ca/desautels/files/desautels/CM_JFEC_05.pdf)", JFinEmetr (2005). However, I am not sure how to go about obtaining a series of probability transforms from truncated RNDs. I am also very new to Matlab so any guidance regarding the implementation of Christoffersen and Mazzotta (2005) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is wierd,, the public (SSRN) version of Christoffen and Mazzotta does not have a section 5b. What kinds of "probability transforms" does it use?

Comment: Sorry, it should be section 2.3 (page 11) in the SSRN version. I have edited my question to make the correction and have also provided a link to the paper.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the *cumulative* RNDs - these form a bijection from the observed returns through to (0,1). Reverse the map so that a random uniform samples a return from the distribution. Non-parametric sampling that recovers the estimated terminal density goven by vanilla option prices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer James, I think it cleared up a lot. I am not sure I understand how the 'uniform' probability transform is related to the cdf, I saw this expression in a paper: $U_{t, h} \equiv \int_{-\infty}^{S_{t+h}}f_{t, h}(u)du\equiv F_{t, h}(S_{t+h})$. The right-hand side makes sense but I don't quite know how that is equivalent to the uniform probability transform, $U_{t, h}$.

Comment: I was able to calculate the cdfs and have applied the inverse of the standard normal cdf to them to obtain a series of normal transform variables, would the next step be just applying the GMM to test whether their central moments are equal to those of the normal distribution?